# What is wrong in my method of calculation of center of mass of a hollow right circular cone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, integration, geometry

[image]

In the figure above, it must be noted that $R-r$ is Infinitesimal small, but it is shown bigger in the figure.

here $y_{cm}$ is $y$-coordinate of center of mass (COM), $m$ is the total mass of the hollow cone.

But now when i saw the correct answer on google it was not the same as i got, can you say what i have done wrong

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Also, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @HarshAgarwal The difference if the wall of the shell has a uniform thickness is that $dV$ is proportional to $y$ not $y^2$, the COM integral contains $y^2$ instead of $y^3$ and the final result is $\frac h 3$ instead of $\frac h 4$.